# JavaScript to Navigate to Home Page and Login

Tags: javascript, authentication, onload

I have written bookmarklet to navigate to Home Page of my application:

```
javascript:(function(){
    location.href="<Address of my app>";
})();
```

Similarly, I have written another bookmarklet to fill User Name and Password and Login into the application:

```
javascript:void
(user=document.getElementById("username"),                                           
user.value="uname>",
user.focus(),
user.blur(),
pwd=document.getElementById("password"),
pwd.value="<password>",
pwd.focus(),pwd.blur(),
$(":button").click())
```

Now I wanted to write a single bookmarklet which can both navigate to Home Page and do login.

```
javascript:(function(){
    location.href="<Address of my app"; }
)();

function login(){
    user=document.getElementById("username");
    user.value="<Uname>"; 
    user.focus(); 
    user.blur();
    pwd=document.getElementById("password");
    pwd.value="<password>";
    pwd.focus(); 
    pwd.blur();
    $(":button").click();
} 
window.onload = function(){ 
    setTimeout( function(){ login(); }, 2000);
};
```

**But I facing two problems here:**

**1)** If I run the bookmarklet from Chrome's Bookmark Manager, the onload method is being called before the Login Page loads, so it is not able to find the given DOM elements.

**2)** If I run the bookmarklet directly from bookmarks list (listed on top of my Chrome), the onload method is not being called at all.

Comment: Are you loading the login page via a frame of some kind and embedding it in the homepage?

Comment: @Mark: I am not very sure, what you mean. Login Page and Home Page are two different pages in app. My requirement is to open browser and click on bookmark, which should open the login page, put user name and password followed by clicking on login button.

For Example: Chrome is Opened and a bookmark is clicked, then it should take to facebook login page, put the username and password and click login, so that, the user's home page is opened!

Comment: That's excellent clarification. I don't have a good answer, but there is some info about onload in Bookmarklets here: http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/implementing-bookmarklets.html He talks here about inserting your own javascript to run on a page and the insertion triggering the onload event (instead of binding it to the window load). Specifically:  "It creates a <script> element, adds the attributes src and onload and inserts it directly after the <head> element. The insertion causes the script to load and once loading is finished, the function pointed to by onload will be called."

Comment: I had another thought about this, the onload method can't be chained the same way Document On Ready, can be, have you tried changing the onload to Document Ready? Maybe the page you are trying to trigger the onload on already has an onload declared and being called, which would block additional onloads (like yours) from being called.